# Android Maps API v2: Zoom in on current location and marker

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a map included in an application. I need the map to zoom in on the a marker and the users location but keep the marker centered. The zoom in works perfectly, but of course doesn't center the marker on the map.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onLocationChanged(location);

        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
        .include(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
        .include((new LatLng(52.3563, 4.8790)))
        .build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 35));


    }
}
```

What is the best way to keep both within the bounds but keep the marker centered? I can't seem to find a solution in the official documentation.

Answer (score 6):

There are two functions I would call, one for centering the marker and an other one to zoom on the map until your current location is still visible.

My solution for zooming to a point with a 15 zoom level:

```
myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngToCenter, 1));
```

zooming until all markers are still visible (change code to fit the marker and your position instead):

```
public void fitZoomAndPositionToMapByMarkers() {

    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    List<MyMapMarker> markersShownOnMap = getMarkersToShow();

    for (MyMapMarker item : markersShownOnMap) {

        int lat = (int) (item.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lon = (int) (item.getLongitude() * 1E6);

        maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
        minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
        maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
        minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);
    }

    double latitudeToGo = (maxLat + minLat) / 1E6 / 2;
    double longitudeToGo = (maxLon + minLon) / 1E6 / 2;
    LatLng toCenter = new LatLng(latitudeToGo, longitudeToGo);

    centerCameraToProperPosition(toCenter);

    LatLng southWestLatLon = new LatLng(minLat / 1E6, minLon / 1E6);
    LatLng northEastLatLon = new LatLng(maxLat / 1E6, maxLon / 1E6);

    zoomInUntilAllMarkersAreStillVisible(southWestLatLon, northEastLatLon);
}
```

Hope this helps!

```
private void zoomInUntilAllMarkersAreStillVisible(final LatLng southWestLatLon, final     LatLng northEastLatLon) {

    myMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {

            myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southWestLatLon, northEastLatLon), 50));
            myMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngToCenter, 1));  WORKED FOR ME :) THANKS

Comment: centerCameraToProperPosition(toCenter); where is it defined?

Comment: you can solve it by using myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(toCenter))

Answer (score 2):

Hello i have found a nice and easy way using LatLngbounds:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(latlngSW, latlngNE, 50));
```

this function will use the most SW point and the most NE point to create a rectangle to center the view with 50 padding, but u need to check first which one of the points should be given as first or second parameter, here is my code:

```
public void centerMap(LatLng latLng){
    if(fenceMarker != null){
        LatLngBounds center; 
        LatLng fence = fenceMarker.getPosition();
        if(fence.latitude < latLng.latitude || fence.longitude < latLng.longitude)
            center = new LatLngBounds(fenceMarker.getPosition(), latLng);
        else{
            center = new LatLngBounds(latLng, fenceMarker.getPosition());
        }
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(center, 50));
    }
}
```

The 2 points are my position latLng and the marker I have for the GeoFence, fenceMarker.

I call this function centerMap(latLng) from the onLocationChanged():

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); 
    centerMap(latLng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting Boundaries** -

An overload of the method, **newLatLngBounds(boundary, width, height, padding)** allows
 you to specify a **width and height** in pixels for a rectangle, with the intention that
 these correspond to the dimensions of the map. The rectangle is positioned such **that its center is the same as that of the map's view** (so that if the dimensions specified are the same as those of the map's view, then the rectangle coincides with the map's view). The returned CameraUpdate will move the camera such that the specified **LatLngBounds are centered on screen within the given rectangle** at the greatest possible zoom level, taking into account the padding required.

Reference- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#target_location

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I dont see that putting the marker itself at the center of the screen and the users location anywhere else within the boundaries.